# Let $G=\langle x,y|x^{8}=y^{2}=e,yxyx^{3}=e \rangle$. Show that $|G|\leq16$. Assuming that $|G|=16$, find the center of $G$ and the order of xy.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G=\langle x,y|x^{8}=y^{2}=e,yxyx^{3}=e \rangle$. Show that $|G|\leq16$. Assuming that $|G|=16$, find the center of $G$ and the order of xy.

I am having trouble with this proof. I have a hint but do not understand how to piece it together. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Big hint: rewrite the last relation in the form $yx=x^ay^b$ for some $a$ and $b$. Now, can you see how to use this to write each element in $G$ in the form $x^my^n$ for some $m$ and $n$? What do the first two relations imply for how tightly you can bound $m$ and $n$?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part you can use the commutativity relation $yx=x^{-3}y^{-1}$ to rewrite every element in the group in the form $x^my^n$, with $0\le
 m\lt8$ and $0\le n\lt2$.  This gives $|G|\le16$.

Assuming $|G|=16$, we have $G=\{e,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6,x^7,y,xy,x^2y,x^3y,x^4y,x^5y,x^6y,x^7y\}$.

For the center, if it had order $8$, the quotient would be cyclic and $G$ would be abelian.  So it has order $2$ or $4$. The center has order $2$, and is $\{e,x^4\}$.

It's looking more and more like we have $D_8$.

Finally, the order of $xy$ is $8$.  Because $(xy)^8=(xyxy)^4=(xx^{-3})^4=(x^{-2})^4=x^{-8}=e$, and no smaller power gives $e$.

Comment: please add why $\ |G/Z(G)|\ne 4$ as it would give $\ G$ is abelian.

Comment: You mean $|G/Z(G)|\ne2$? @ManjoyDas

Comment: For the centre, it has order $\ 2$ or $\ 4$. you took $\ 2$ and omitted the possibility of being $\ 4$.

Comment: Right.  I did a little trial and error, but didn't include that.  @ManjoyDas

Comment: would you mind sharing your argument?  @ManjoyDas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107024/discussion-between-manjoy-das-and-chris-custer).